# How to filter XDocument's result?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am fetching some data about schools via a webservice. Returning XML looks like this:

```
<document>
  <orgType>
   <orgParent>
      <parentID>21</parentID>
      <parentName>My School</parentName>
      <unit>
        <unitID>2</unitID>
        <unitName>Logistics</unitName>
        <childUnit>
          <childUnitName></childUnitName>
          <opB>
            <Program>601</Program>
            <ProgramName>Short</ProgramName>
            <Method>903001</Method>
            <Type>915001</Type>
          </opB>
        </childUnit>
      </unit>
      <unit>
        <unitID>3</unitID>
        <unitName>Trading</unitName>
        <childUnit>
          <childUnitName></childUnitName>
          <opB>
            <Program>731</Program>
            <ProgramName>Short</ProgramName>
            <Method>903001</Method>
            <Type>915001</Type>
          </opB>
        </childUnit>
      </unit>
      <unit>
        <unitID>4</unitID>
        <unitName>Food Control and Quality Analysis</unitName>
        <childUnit>
          <childUnitName></childUnitName>
          <opB>
            <Program>734</Program>
            <ProgramName>Short</ProgramName>
            <Method>903001</Method>
            <Type>915001</Type>
          </opB>
        </childUnit>
      </unit>
    </orgParent>
     <orgParent>
      <parentID>16</parentID>
      <parentName>Her School</parentName>
      <unit>
        <unitID>1</unitID>
        <unitName>Poultry</unitName>
        <childUnit>
          <childUnitName></childUnitName>
          <opB>
            <Program>573</Program>
            <ProgramName>Short</ProgramName>
            <Method>903001</Method>
            <Type>915001</Type>
          </opB>
        </childUnit>
      </unit>
      <unit>
        <unitID>27</unitID>
        <unitName>Forestry</unitName>
        <childUnit>
          <childUnitName></childUnitName>
          <opB>
            <Program>856</Program>
            <ProgramName>Short</ProgramName>
            <Method>903001</Method>
            <Type>915001</Type>
          </opB>
        </childUnit>
      </unit>
    </orgParent>
  </orgType>
</document>
```

I can get parentID and parentName values into seperate List objects.

```
    XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();

    List<string> parentUnitNames = getParentUnitNames();
    List<string> parentUnitIDs = getParentUnitIDs();

    int i = 0;
    foreach (string parentUnitName in parentUnitNames)
    {
         contentDiv.InnerHtml += String.Format("<h2>{0}</h2>", parentUnitName);

        List<string> unitNames = getUnitNames(parentUnitID[i]);
        List<string> unitIDs = getUnitIDs(parentUnitID[i]);

        foreach (string unitName in unitNames)
        {
            contentDiv.InnerHtml += String.Format("<h4>{0}</h4>", unitName);
        }
        i++;
    }
```

the problem is all deparments from all schools are listed in all schools. In other words If the first school has three departments and the second school has two departments then the first school's department list have 5 items and the second school's department list have same 5 items too.

According to the code above page has a view like this

```
<h2>My School</h2>
    <h4>Logistics</h4>
    <h4>Trading</h4>
    <h4>Food Control and Quality Analysis</h4>
    <h4>Poutry</h4>
    <h4>Forestry</h4>
<h2>Her School</h2>
    <h4>Logistics</h4>
    <h4>Trading</h4>
    <h4>Food Control and Quality Analysis</h4>
    <h4>Poutry</h4>
    <h4>Forestry</h4>
```

which should be

```
<h2>My School</h2>
    <h4>Logistics</h4>
    <h4>Trading</h4>
    <h4>Food Control and Quality Analysis</h4>
<h2>Her School</h2>
    <h4>Poutry</h4>
    <h4>Forestry</h4>
```

I should write a Where<> limiter to focus on the school's own node for each school but do not know how and what.

My methods are like the following:

```
protected List<string> getParentUnitIDs()
{
    List<string> myList = new List<string>();

    var parentUnitIDs = XDocument.Parse(service.getOrganizationTree())
                                  .Descendants("parentID")
                                  .Select(x => x.Value);


    foreach (string s in parentUnitIDs)
    {
        myList.Add(s);
    }
    return myList;
}


protected List<string> getUnitIDs(string parentUnitID)
{
    List<string> myList = new List<string>();

    var unitIDs = XDocument.Parse(service.getOrganizationTree())
                               .Descendants("unitID")
                               .Select(x => x.Value)
                              //Where() condition should be here I guess

    foreach (string s in unitIDs )
    {
        myList.Add(s);
    }
    return myList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
var result = xdoc.Root.Descendants("orgParent")
                      .Where(x => x.Element("parentName").Value == "My School")
                      .Descendants("unit")
                      .Select(x => x.Element("unitName").Value).ToList();
```

Here I have hard-coded `parentName` value as "My School", you can replace with the value you are passing to your custom function. Also, replace `xdoc` variable I have used with yours `XDocument.Parse(service.getOrganizationTree())` as I have compiled this code in my local.

Comment: @zkanoca - I saw your other post. Tell me where you are facing issue? This block of code is giving me correct output. You need to just call it as a method, as you posted in your original question.

Answer (score 1):

What if you tried and did this in all the same sweep? Like

```
contentDiv.InnerHtml = "";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var parents = doc.XPathSelectElements("//orgParent");
foreach (XElement parent in parents)
{
    contentDiv.InnerHtml += string.Format("<h2>{0}</h2>", parent.Value);
    var units = parent.XPathSelectElements("//unit");
    foreach (XElement unit in units)
    {
        contentDiv.InnerHtml += string.Format("<h4>{0}</h4>", unit.Value);
    }
}
```

Best regards,

zerratar

Comment: But I will find a way out. Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can filter selected nodes. I mean I should write `var units = parent.XPathSelectElements("//unit").Where(????);`. But do not know what to write

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this from an object perspective rather than trying to work with the XML.

Transform the XML into an object model and then work with the object model.

```
class OrgParent
{
  int ID {get;set;}
  string Name {get;set;}
  List<Unit> Units {get; set;}
}

class Unit
{ 
   int ID {get;set;}
  string Name {get;set;}
}
```

..meaning your code becomes:

```
XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();

List<OrgParent> parents = GetParents(); //Transforms all XML into object model

foreach (var parent in parents)
{
    contentDiv.InnerHtml += String.Format("<h2>{0}</h2>", parent.Name);

    foreach (var unit in parent.Units)
    {
        contentDiv.InnerHtml += String.Format("<h4>{0}</h4>", unit.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh oh! Funny how similar our answers are xD I didn't see yours until after I posted mine either.

Comment: Yes, except I'm going full object model instead of just working with the XML, but the concept of maintaining the relational integrity between the items is there. ;)